# Shutdown sftp camel route after downloading all files from sftp folder

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am developing an spring-boot application to download files from sftp using camel route. Here is my code

```
from("sftp://username@host/folder")
   .convertBodyTo(File.class)
   .process("processor")
   .routeId(routeId);
```

I want to shutdown this route after downloading all files from the given sftp folder. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FTP Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/ftp-component.html) implements [Polling Consumer](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/polling-consumer.html), so you can use `sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle` option. With this option set to `true`, the Consumer emits empty message, when folder is empty, which you can then use in [Content Based Router EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-based-router-eip.html).

To stop route you can use simple processor, [ControlBus EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/controlbus-component.html), or any other approach described in [FAQ - How can I stop a route from a route?](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html).

```
from("sftp://username@host/folder?sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true")
    .routeId(routeId)
    .choice()
        .when(body().isNull())
            .toF("controlbus:route?routeId=%s&action=stop&async=true", routeId)
        .otherwise()
            .convertBodyTo(File.class)
            .process("processor");
```